# How many types of resource layout does a ListView support?

Tags: android, listview, layout, resources

I'd like to know how many types of built-in resource XML layouts a `ListView` has.

For example,

- android.R.id.simple_list_item.xml
- android.R.id.simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml

which one can pass to an `Adapter` to inflate the list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find them in the [R.layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html) reference.